# Image hyperlink position

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

Is there a way to put a hyperlink on a specific coordinate on a image?

Ex

```
_____________________________________
|                                   |
|   xxx                             |
|   xxx                             |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                    zzz            |
|                    zzz            |
|                                   |
|___________________________________|
```

Is there a way to set hyperlink on xxx position and a separate hyperlink on the zzz position of the image. How would I go about starting this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/rLwG2/ - This is a lazy ass way of doing it. I generate 3 elements more or less automatically with jquery, but those could be put around the image(s) manually as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets"
usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
<area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
<area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

more info about HTML  coords Attribute  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done with [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map)

```
<map name="a">
  <area shape="rect" coords="25,25,75,75" href='url'>
</map>
<img usemap="#a" src=image.png>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to approach this problem.  Others have already mentioned using MAP, but it sounds like you might mean you want to position text links over the image rather than just create clickable zones.  Assuming you want to position the links at pixel level, one way to do that looks like this:

```
<div id="myimagediv">
    <a id="linkxxx" href="xxx.example.com">xxx</a>
    <a id="linkzzz" href="zzz.example.com">zzz</a>
</div>

#myimagediv {
width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('myimage.jpg');
}
#myimagediv a {
    position: absolute;
}
#linkxxx {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
#linkzzz {
    top: 70px;
    left: 70px;
}
```

Comment: @Kenster re: edit -- oops, this answer is from a long while back but I clearly just didn’t think about what that example url would really *be*, apologies

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by a process called 'image mapping.' It can be quite tedious because you'll have to map it pixel by pixel. There are tools on the internet which map images for you.